# understanding recursion for dot product in java

Tags: java, recursion

Could anyone give me some clue about how could I Transform this code to recursion:

```
public class arrayExample {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int[] a = {2,2,2,2};
        int[] b = {2,2,2,2};
        int n = a.length;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sum += a[i] * b[i];    
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

So to do this do product with recursion.

Comment: Start by writing some code. Oh and please respect Java coding conventions. Class names should always start with an uppercase letter

Comment: **too broad...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so hoping you have tried it before this is one possible way to code it.

```
public class ArrayExample {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int[] a = {2,2,2,2};
    int[] b = {2,2,2,2};
    int n = a.length;
    int result = recurseSum(a, b, n-1);
    System.out.println(result);
}

public static int recurseSum(int[] a, int[] b, int n){
    if(n == 0)
        return a[0]*b[0];
    else{
        return (a[n] * b[n]) + recurseSum(a,b,n-1);
    }
}
}
```

This code is basically doing the same thing in the iteration.

The recursive call happens 4 times. When n hits 0, a[0]*b[0] is returned to the higher call. so basically from right to left it happens as follows:

a[3]*b[3] + a[2]*b[2] + a[1]*b[1] + a[0]*b[0]

Answer (score 2):

You asked for a hint, so I'm not giving you the complete solution. When you want to process a list (or an array) recursively, the concept is nearly always:

```
public int recursiveFunction(List l, int carry) {
    if (l.isEmpty()) {
        return carry;
    }
    return recursiveFunction(l.subList(1, l.size()), operation(carry, l.get(0));
}
```

Where `operation` is whatever you want to do with your list. `carry` is used to provide an initial value (in the first call) and save the interim results.

You just have to change the code so it uses two arrays instead of one list and choose the correct operation.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to make a loop into a recursion is to answer these two questions:

- What happens when the loop executes zero times?
- If the loop has already executed `n-1` times, how do I compute the result after the `n`-th iteration?

The answer to the first case produces your base case; the answer to the second question explains how to do the recursive invocation.

In your case, the answers are as follows:

- When the loop executes zero times, the `sum` is zero.
- When the loop executed `n-1` times, add `a[n] * b[n]` to the previous result.

This can be translated into a recursive implementation

```
static int dotProduct(int[] a, int[] b, int n) {
    ... // your implementation here
}
```